# How to get SYSTEM time of 12:00PM of the day

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my Visual C++ program, I want to have a SYSTEMTIME variable equals to 12:00PM (noon) of the day. I am not very sure how to make this happen.

Pointers are appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: @SLaks I think he means he wants to generate a DateTime value equal to noon of the current day - presumably to compare the current time against. `DateTime.TimeOfDay` would probably work, compared against a `TimeSpan` of 12h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetLocalTime(&st);
st.wHour = 12;
st.wMinute = st.wSecond = st.wMilliseconds = 0;
```